# Error in file reading with FileReader and readAsArrayBuffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, bufferedreader, reader

I have below piece of code in my app.js through which I am saving details of a file (uploaded from local) selected by a user in mongo DB. But the application crashes with error "invalid glob pattern: undefined" when I click on submit button of the page from where the file is being uploaded.

```
app.post("/documents", function(req, res){

 var name = req.body.documentname;
 var remarks = req.body.documentremarks;
 //File Reader
 var document = req.body.Document;
 const reader = new FileReader(); 
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(document)  
 //Upload to IPFS
 addToIpfs(reader, function (err, ipfsid){
     if (err) {
        console.log(err)            
    } else {
        var newDocument = {name: name, remarks: remarks, hash:ipfsid}; 
        Blockproof.create(newDocument, function(err, newlyCreated) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                 //redirect back to documents page
                res.redirect("/documents");
            }
        });     
    }
});
```

I have installed npm package 'file-reader:1.1.1' for the app which is declared as

```
  FileReader = require("file-reader");
```

Please guide if I am missing any point here or doing anything wrong and how to solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are not allowed to create the instance of FileReader. why don't you try node's inbuilt fs module.